# I cannot see the modal pop up when chrome is running via selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to automate filling a form to upload marks of each student.

Scenario when filling the form manually:

1. Click on a button, modal pop up appears, fill form.

Problem when automated:

1. Clicking on the button does not open modal pop up.
2. I tried clicking on the same button manually by adding `time.sleep()` when chrome is being controlled by automated software, it still doesn't show the modal pop up.

Can the modal pop up be blocked when I try running the form through selenium?

I am running the chrome web driver for v78+

Comment: Are you adding any options to the driver creation? something like `webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities()`?

Comment: no, not adding any options. Using ` driver=webdriver.chrome('path/to/webdriver')`

Comment: What kind of modal are you expecting? A system (OS) level dialog or an html modal?

Comment: Also some code may help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

### you can check "disable-popup-blocking" option for the google Chrome

1. Click the Customize and control Google Chrome menu (the three dots in the upper right corner)
2. Select Settings.
3. Click Advanced at the bottom.
4. Under Privacy and security, click the Site Settings button.
5. Select Pop-ups and redirects.
6. To disable the pop-up blocker uncheck the Blocked (recommended) box.
7. To enable pop-ups on specific sites, check Blocked (recommended) and click Add next to Allow and enter the URL(s).

Comment: It doesn't help. It works as expected when done manually through chrome, the unexpected behavior shows only when chrome is controlled by an automated software.